# Problems with Where Condition in Pivot Table Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hello I am working on a project, that in this part, to get a dependent dropdown i want to get all  the «Areas de Interesse» that are attached to a specific user, getting this, by his ID, that is in the pivot table.

These are my migrations:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('profile_photo_path', 2048)->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('area_interesse', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('area_interesse');
    $table->string('area_interesse_ing');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('utilizador_interesse', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger("id_utilizador");
    $table->foreign('id_utilizador')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');;
    $table->unsignedBigInteger("id_interesse");
    $table->foreign('id_interesse')->references('id')->on('area_interesse');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And my models:

```
class AreaInteresse extends Model
{
    protected $table = "area_interesse";

    public function users(){
            return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'utilizador_interesse', 'id_interesse' , 'id_utilizador');
        
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function interesses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(AreaInteresse::class, 'utilizador_interesse', 'id_utilizador', 'id_interesse');
    }
}
```

In my controller i tried to do this, base on every example i saw, has for testing, i am trying to get all «Areas de Interesse» that are related to the user with id 11

```php
$interesses = AreaInteresse::with('users')
    ->whereHas('users', function($q){
        $q->wherePivot('id_utilizador', 11); 
    })
    ->get();
```

However i am getting this error and i have no idea why it's happening, and why it is assuming i am trying to call a column «pivot»

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `area_interesse` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `utilizador_interesse` on `users`.`id` = `utilizador_interesse`.`id_utilizador` where `area_interesse`.`id` = `utilizador_interesse`.`id_interesse` and `pivot` = id_utilizador))
```

Comment: why not using User model?

Comment: It is giving me the same error.  It says Pivot column doesn't exist (and it is right), however as i understood with the examples i saw,  with this code i think in the «wherePivot» condition , i was saying that i get all the data ,where in the pivot table  the Id_utilizador is 11.  I  tried  put just where ('utilizador_interesse.id_utilizador', '=',11) and it says this table doesn t exist.    But my point on doing with the AreaInteresse model,  was  to  get all the «area de interesse», that a user has  for a dropdown that is dependent to a user dropdown

Comment: Start by considering that, if your user is your "utilizador", then you don't need to complicate your life assigning different names to the columns, unles you create a new Utilizador Model which could extend from User Model. In your ```AreaInteresse``` model you're creating the ```users()``` relationship linked to the ```User``` model, but this model has nothing yo do with the "utilizador" word (no columns, no relatioships, nothing related to it).

Comment: Ok, i was able to get the info i need from the query.  with this ``` $interesses = User::with('interesses')
        ->whereHas('interesses', function($q){
          $q->where('utilizador_interesse.id_utilizador', '=', $request->id); 
      })
      ->get();  ```    However now i am struggling  with getting this data to the dependent dropdown, because all the examples i find are from one to many relation,  and mine is a many to many

Comment: Problem Solved. Got the idea to change where «Area de Interesse» was assigned to , and with this change it till get things way more simple for me  ( I was going to assign Area de Interesse to the users, instead i will assign it directly to the job, some of the users are assign to, so when i need to create this jobs , i don't have to use any Dependent Dropdown, by getting the «area de interesses» assigned to the user that i choose,  Instead when i am choosing the user, i will choose also the «area de interesse» and with relations, this «area de interesse» is automatically assigned to my user

Comment: i suggest using where clause with the model relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I am trying to get all «Areas de Interesse» that are related to the user with id 11"

This is exactly why relationships are defined between models. Just instantiate the user and then get the related models:

```php
$user = User::findOrFail(11);
$interesses = $user->interesses;
```

As mentioned in comments, and worth repeating here, you should call your class `Utilizadore` instead of `User`, or change table and column names to match the name of the class.

Comment: Thank you!    Now  i am trying to group some data, to avoid replicates, using the Group By, however it s not working (and it is not due to the strick being true, in config)   .  If i put the query this way $mentores= User::role('mentor')->with('mentoria.interesses')->get();   i get the results i expect ( all the users that have mentor role, , and their data in mentoria table and in areaInteresses table). However if i use this  $mentores= User::role('mentor')->with('mentoria.interesses')->groupBy('mentoria.id_interesse')->get();  it gives me an error, by saying mentoria.id_interesse is unknown

Comment: * continue  *   unknown column ,  and the query that appears in the error only shows the part between the User and the Roles, ignoring the other tables (however if i try put  role_id, or users.Id, it gives me also an error (however i want to group all the data,  by the Id_interesse, that is the foreign key from the areaInteresse table

Comment: This sounds like another question. You can't group by relationship property during query. Get the results and use `Collection::groupBy` method instead.

Comment: Yes, it was another question, sorry.   I will  try it.  thanks